# Work with Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, mysqli

I have a really hard time understanding sessions. I want to store `card_id`in sessions , how do i do that?

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT value FROM card_credit 
WHERE card_id= (select distinct card_id 
                from Raw where 
                 id = (select max(b.id) from Raw as b))");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $card_id = $rows['value'];

        echo "<p>Saldo: $card_id";
```

Comment: use this $_SESSION["card_id"] = $card_id;

Comment: use `session_start()`, `$_SESSION[]` and the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with sessions. The only relevant line (starting point for an answer) is `$card_id = `

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SESSION` throughout your application.
To store sessions you'll always need to start with `session_start();`

If we look at your example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT value FROM card_credit 
                WHERE card_id= (select distinct card_id 
                from Raw where 
                 id = (select max(b.id) from Raw as b))");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $card_id = $rows['value'];
        $_SESSION['card_id'] = $card_id; //Set session variable
        echo "<p>Saldo: $card_id";
    }
```

Now we can use this session variable on another page for example test.php:

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['card_id']; //Echo's the id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code use `session_start`

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT value FROM card_credit 
WHERE card_id= (select distinct card_id 
                from Raw where 
                 id = (select max(b.id) from Raw as b))");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $card_id = $rows['value'];

        echo "<p>Saldo: $card_id";
        $_SESSION['card_id']=$card_id;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    $resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT value FROM card_credit WHERE card_id= (select distinct card_id from Raw where id = (select max(b.id) from Raw as b))");

    if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){
        $card_id = $rows['value'];
        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION["card_id"] = $card_id;
        //echo "Session variables are set.";
        echo "<p>Saldo: $card_id";
    }
?>
```